# Second Audio Files Loops Unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I would like for two audio files to play one after the other and then stop, using only one audio tag. The problem is when the second audio file plays, it repeats for a while and then just stops. I thought it was a bubbling issue so I used `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` but that didn't work. I also tried `e.preventDefault()` `e.stopPropagation()` and `return false`. None of which worked as well. I feel like my code is probably off so if someone can tell me whats wrong as well as a better way to go about this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('#audio').on({
    'ended' : function(e) {
        this.src= 'sounds/new_speech.mp3';
        this.play();
        $('#audio').on({
            'ended' : function(){
                document.querySelector('#audio').src= 'sounds/new_sound.mp3';
            }
        });
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }

});
```

Comment: why do you bind the event twice? more than twice probably... if you want to re-define the handler, you need to remove the old one, lest they both apply, which is what you describe.

Comment: thought I needed another `ended` event to change the audio back to the original file after the second audio finished playing because I'm only using one audio tag. Please let me know the best way to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use the same event for one tag playing many tracks:

```
<audio id=audio controls autoplay 
         src="http://ia700706.us.archive.org/27/items/3112011-08-06/3.03.ComeOriginal.mp3"></audio>

<script>  

    var tracks=[
        "http://ia700706.us.archive.org/27/items/3112011-08-06/3.04.WildNights.mp3",
        "http://ia700706.us.archive.org/27/items/3112011-08-06/3.05.Eons.mp3"
    ];

    $("#audio").on({ended:function(e) {
        var track=tracks.shift();
        if(track){
            this.src= track;
            this.play();
        }
    }});

</script>
```

live demo: http://pagedemos.com/74yy2ur65zev/